# How to upload the custom image in magento 2 with Uploader factory?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to upload the image into custom folder and into database, i am using the uploader factory library but while adding this i am getting below mentioned error..

> Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or
>   after any declare call in the script in
>   /home/mysitename/public_html/app/code/Cmsmart/Marketplace/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php
>   on line 3

```php
public function __construct(
       Context $context,
       Session $customerSession,
       ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
       StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
       Address $addressHelper,
       UrlFactory $urlFactory,
       FormFactory $formFactory,
       SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
       RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
       AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
       CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
       CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
       Registration $registration,
       Escaper $escaper,
       CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
       DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
       AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
       \Cmsmart\Marketplace\Helper\Data $marketplaceHelperData,
      \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFactory $dateFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
)
```

Comment: issue is namespace declaration, make sure that you have declared namespace as first statement.

Comment: Hello Ramkrishan, Thanks for your message I am using the Namespace as first statement but getting the same error.

namespace Cmsmart\Marketplace\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;